# How can i read a remote file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, file, bitbucket, fs

I need to read a file in node.js that's located on bitbucket. 
I am new to node and tried the fs module, but I do not understand how I can pass in the file's location. Is there any another module for reading a remote file?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is that file publicly accessible? If yes, I can provide a code snippet for the same.

Comment: Nope @Aakash It is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Bitbucket.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitbucket) npm package which does the job for you. This package acts as an wrapper for all API's offered by BitBucket, Once you establish a connection with your bitbucket account through this package, you can call the [filename](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D) end point to get your file contents.

This endpoint returns the actual file contents and not the artifact's metadata.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @David it is a clean and simple package. it worked just fine :)